# JPA Specification subquery with AND doesn't work as expected

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a weird issue, I need to connect a View (Workbench) with a table (FA_TICKET), to stablish this connection I use IN operator with subselect... This is going ok... But... When I try to add a new filter to it, it not resolves.

```
Subquery<Workbench> subFr = query.subquery(Workbench.class);
Root<FrTicket> rootFrTicket = subFr.from(FrTicket.class);
subFr.select(rootFrTicket.get("ticketId"));
Predicate pred = root.get("ticketNum").in(subFr);
criteriaBuilder.and(pred, criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type"), TicketType.FR_TICKET));
predicates.add(pred);

....
//predicates is defined at begining and have other filters
return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

When I see the sub-query section, it should be like:

```
select .... from Workbench where ...  and (ticketNum in (SUBSELECT) and type = ?)
```

But... The line about ticket type is never resolved and I see:

```
select .... from Workbench where ...  and (ticketNum in (SUBSELECT))
```

If I change the order when define the and, I see this:

```
Predicate pred = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type"), TicketType.FR_TICKET);
criteriaBuilder.and(pred, root.get("ticketNum").in(subFr));

select .... from Workbench where ...  and (type = ?)
```

How I can include this type in the same group?
Because I need to stablish a filter with other kind of Ticket entities, with a different type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem apears with **enums**, they are problematic with CriteriaBuilder class.

So, if I make this change:

```
Subquery<Workbench> subFr = query.subquery(Workbench.class);
Root<FrTicket> rootFrTicket = subFr.from(FrTicket.class);
subFr.select(rootFrTicket.get("ticketId"));
Predicate pred = root.get("ticketNum").in(subFr);
criteriaBuilder.and(pred, criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type").as(String.class), TicketType.FR_TICKET).name());
predicates.add(pred);

....
//predicates is defined at begining and have other filters
return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

Works smooth.